# How to indicate turn off javascript by server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net

Sometimes i saw in the most web pages that, When i turn off javascript in my web browser and refresh the page which say some warning messages.Such as "Javascript Required.","The page running well when turn on javascript." My question is how to indicate by the server turn off my browser javascript? and it's does by any specific code in server side languages as PHP or ASP?

Comment: What do you want as behaviour? Checking server side if javascript is disabled in client browser or checking it only client side?

Comment: Hey you try now, Turn off your javascript in browser and then go to http://www.facebook.com. See what's happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) HTML tag. The content inside will be shown when JavaScript is turned off.

This is done by the browser.

Comment: Thanks Halcyon! for your help